# 'I watch less TV than you' or 'I watch TV less than you'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which one is grammatically correct or idiomatic?

> 1. I watch less/more TV than you.
> 2. I watch TV  less/more than you.

---

> 3. I have less/more money than you.
> 4. I have money less/more than you.

Comment: 1: Fine. 2: Fine. 3: Fine. 4: Said nobody ever.

Comment: Thank you.Can we say that both 1 and 3 are grammatically correct but 2 is only idiomatic?

Comment: 2 is fine and idiomatic.

Comment: Good question. Robusto and Centaurus agree on the basic answer (and I with them), but that leaves the *why:* why is 2 all right and 4 not? Both are using "less/more than you" to modify the main verb (where in 1 and 3 "less/more" modifies the verb's direct object). Money and TV are both being treated as quantifiable mass nouns in 1 and 3. I suspect that the difference is that "TV" has idiomatically come to complement the verb "watch" otherwise than as its direct object, and the same is not true of "money" with "have"--not yet.

Comment: @Brian: I think it has more to do with the verb *have*. I swim less than you, eat less than you, read less than you, etc. are all fine. But "I *have* less than you" is functionally and semantically different.

Comment: @Robusto how about 'I read less book/poem than you'  vs 'I read book/poem less than you'.

Comment: @Murat: Semantic difference there too. For example, "I drink less beer than you" has a slightly different meaning from "I drink beer less than you."

Comment: You cannot read *less book*, book is countable and should be in the plural ---> *"I read less **books** than you"* OR **"...fewer books..."** There are some who insist on the latter, but nowadays the term "less" is preferred and the most common.

Comment: @Robusto: Good point. The difference being that the "amount" of *watching TV* you do would only normally be understood to mean *total time spent watching TV*. Whereas with *drinking beer* it's meaningful to quantify either the *quantity* (more/less beer) or the *frequency* (drink beer more/less [often]). But there's a third possible distinction. Suppose you drink half a pint every night, always taking less than one minute. I only drink on Friday nights, but I spend all evening down the pub. Do I ***drink beer less*** than you if I always have 3 pints? Do things change if I always have 4 pints?

Comment: @Murat Idioms are never ungrammatical. If their grammar is unusual, they are extragrammatical. English is defined by usage, not 70-year-old books listing rules dubious even at the time they were written.

Answer (score 2):

You can say either:

- I've got money, more than you (do).
- I've got more money than you (do).
- I watch TV, more than you (do).
- I watch more TV than you (do).

"I have money less..." is non-idiomatic and I don't think you'll hear someone saying it.

Comment: Thank you.Can we say that both 1 and 3 are grammatically correct but 2 is only idiomatic and less/more comes before nouns in this kind of sentences.

Comment: @Murat I would use 1 and 3, and would avoid the "money less..." structure, which sounds ungrammatical and wrong.

Comment: I'm not convinced *"I have money less..." is ungrammatical.* Granted, it's non-idiomatic, because we don't normally think in terms of how **often** one might "have money". But I can't see any "grammatical" argument that would allow *"I have infections less [often] than you"* whilst debarring the same construction with *money* (I'm sure the fact that *money* is "uncountable" isn't relevant).

Comment: If the meaning is: *I have money less [often] than you*, then it would be just as sensible as *I have infections less than you.* **But** we assume *more* and *less* always refers to **amount** in connection with money (because it usually does :-) In 3. less is a determiner modifying ***money***, but in 1., 2. & 4., *less* is an adverb modifying *watch TV* (a verb phrase) or *have* in the comparative phrase *less than you*. You can't ***have*** anything to a *smaller extent* (you either have it or you don't), so "smaller extent" is frequency, which we don't intuitively apply to having money.

Answer (score 1):

The first is grammatically correct.

The second is idiomatically omitting the word "often".

> I watch TV less [often] than you.

Comment: What about 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more natural to native speakers:

- I watch TV less [often] than you **do**.
- I don't watch as much TV as you **do**.